# mail system having automated timed e-mail service or Differed delivery option?

Tags: windows, email

There is hardly some need for this feature I guess, but I need a system which delivers the mail at specified delay-time [1 hour, 2 hours later or specified time].

Kindly let me know if you are aware of such feature.

Comment: I need it for birthday wishing and etc ...

Comment: Instead of commenting on your own questions you can just edit them to include further information.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel, I didn't get where to add that sentence, anyway .. the answer has been accepted. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use your OS' task scheduler (`cron`, `Windows Task Scheduler` etc.) to run a program that sends the mail.

Most calendar applications (desktop or online) will also let you send mail when appointments are due.

Comment: ok thanx for the info.